# How to use on-press to open a JavaScript file (react native app)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to use on-press to open a JavaScript file i cant navigate from one file to another using the on-press function,I want to be able to press the button and connect to my other java script file from my first touchable-opacity

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,ImageBackground,button, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions,Button} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator,} from 'react-navigation';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width; 
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const video=[video1.js]

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
   return (

     <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <ImageBackground source={{uri: 'https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/usa_avengers_sb_bkgd8_1024_0ae5b001.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1024%2C576'}}
                         style={{width: width, height: height,}}> 



    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.video}
      style={styles.spiderman}>
          <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Spider-Man-Transparent-Background.png'}}
                 style={{width: 190, height:250,}}/
           >
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using React Navigation to handle routing in your app. in React Navigation, you have to define the structure of your routing and then, you can go to another screen by `this.props.navigation.navigate('name_of_screen')` I suggest you to read the [Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html)